# ASP.NET Web App using the wrong (2.0) CLR version (instead of 4.0)

Tags: iis, web-config, asp.net-4.0

I just deployed an asp.net web app I have been working on to a new dev machine. It's a 4.0 project converted from 3.5. For some reason, I get the following error when I try to hit the site via my IIS website under the Default Website:

> Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

It lists this as being a config error on the ASP.NET error page:

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

However, I notice that at the bottom of the error page, the version information indicates that it is using version 2 instead of version 4. Anyone have ideas about how to fix this?

I have made sure that my default website usese a .net 4 / integrated app pool and i cycled iis after this change was made. Still not luck. Here is my entire web.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="EventMasterConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=BashBidder;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/></system.web>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
</configuration>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure your application pool so it uses version 4.0 of the framework.

[This procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754523%28WS.10%29.aspx) explains how to do it on IIS 7, and [that one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/server-management/VersionsDotnetFramework.aspx) on IIS 6.

Comment: Huh? I believe the OP wants to run his application in version 4.0.

Comment: @Victor, good catch, got the question inverted somehow. Answer updated, thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: Thanks. The app pool is already targeted at version 4, and not version 2. Still no luck.

Comment: You're right. Turns out that there was an error in my webform markup that was causing this. More developments however. I am now getting a 501.19 saying that the config file is invalid (the actual error is that the config file cannot be read). My app runs fine if i hit f5 and let it generate a server address and port from withing VS...but if i try to go through my IIS virtual directory, i get the config error. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Ugh. Scratch that. All is well now. I forgot that I changed the project name and did not update the path of my VD. Thanks for your time.